# In-App purchase Android issue, Google Play is not returning Order ID

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I've successfully managed to implement `In-App Billing` in Android.
The only problem that I 'm having is when I used `restoreTransaction()` method to ask `Google` to return the `order id` with `Signed Data` (purchase status).
It is returning `Null orders array`, even though the item is already purchased.
Here is the Log:

```
08-27 08:30:24.342: I/BillingService(17152): handleCommand() action: com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED
08-27 08:30:24.342: I/BillingService(17152): purchaseStateChanged
08-27 08:30:24.342: I/class com.folio3.games.candymonster.billing.Security(17152): signedData: {"nonce":XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,"orders":[]}
08-27 08:30:24.362: I/class com.folio3.games.candymonster.billing.Security(17152): signature: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: hi Usama, if you provide More information and Relevant code then we will try to help you more

Comment: at the first cycle when i purchase the in-app feature, it is working fine. But once i delete the app from my phone and re-install it, it is saying "you already purchased the item" but then, the item is not appearing. The problem i figure out is that the response from google play does not contain any value in the JSON array of "orders" that is why it is not updated in database.